# how to change kendo standard date format to sql format if the grid on server filtering?

Tags: java, sql, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo grid with server filtering enable , if I click on filtering the date column , the server is receiving the date value as standard one like below

Tue May 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)
I know how to change the date value on update , like below

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {

if (type !== "read" && data.models) {
                                    //return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    var d = new Date( data.models[0].joinDate );

                                    data.models[0].joinDate =  kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-dd");

                                   console.log("date is:"+data.models[0].joinDate);
  // here the server is receiving the join date as yyyy-MM-dd

                                   return data;
                                }
                }
    else
     {
         // it is showing an error if i do like that
        // var d = new Date( data.models[0].joinDate );
       //  data.models[0].joinDate =  kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-dd");
       return data;

     }
```

now my question is what is the function that fires if I click on filter button of the grid which in there I can parse the date to sql format before sending to server . I have tried to do it in read function as mentioned above but it is showing an error .

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve it after long time searching , and this answer for someone who is searching like me .
In order to change the filter field value from standard date-time format to sql format before sending to the server , we need to change the value of that field in filter configuration object of the datasource for the grid .

in order to get the filter configuration object , we can get inside transport.parameterMap like below

```
              parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                                if (type !== "read" && data.models) {
                                    //return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    var d = new Date( data.models[0].joinDate );

                                    data.models[0].joinDate =  kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-dd");

                                   console.log("joinDate in sql frmat for any update on grid:"+data.models[0].joinDate);

                                   return data;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // get currently applied filters from the Grid is data.filter.
                                    var currFilterObj = data.filter;
                                    var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

                                  if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {

                                        if (currentFilters[i].field == "joinDate")
                                        {
                                             var d = new Date(  currentFilters[i].value );
                                             currentFilters[i].value  =  kendo.toString(new Date(d), "yyyy-MM-dd");

                                        console.log("Now joinDate value is in sql format "+currentFilters[i].value);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                  return data;

                                }
```